# What does "crs" in FeatureCollection mean?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I created a map of Toronto wards some years ago when there were 44 wards. Now we have 25 wards and I am attempting to convert the map. I haven't been working with D3 for some time and am not sure where to start.

The previous json had the following definition and was much larger than the one I got from the city
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4269" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GEO_ID": 14630026, "CREATE_ID": 63519, "NAME": "Scarborough-Rouge River (41)", "SCODE_NAME": "41", "LCODE_NAME": "EA41", "TYPE_DESC": "Ward", "TYPE_CODE": "CITW", "OBJECTID": 1, "SHAPE_AREA": 0.0, "SHAPE_LEN": 0.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -79.264840294724905, 43.779537878926838 ],

The new one starts
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[318236.529,4840171.519],[318236.25,4840170.941],

So that I can use the existing javascript I would really like to find a way of converting the new file to the older one. Is that possible?

Comment: This is a GeoJSON thing, it means "coordinate reference system".

Comment: the first json file looks like to contain lon-lat coordinates, the second one uses already projected coordinates using some known projection and they look like meauring relative to the equator for the y-coord

Comment: Unless you know the projection of the second geojson you can't convert the geojson to lat long like the first geojson. Looking at your data I'd imagine that your data in the second file uses a UTM projection and that you are in UTM zone 17 (the numbers represent meters most likely rather than degrees). I'd "unproject" the data to the projection of the other dataset (or EPSG 4326, the datum drift between WGS84 and NAD83 is negligible unless surveying). Once you do this you should be able to use the data without modification of your map's code.

Comment: Would using the shapefile and a different program help - I used Mapshaper ... or ORG2GUI? I got the original json from a website (not using a shapefile) which is why I am confused. If I exported the shapefile as GeoJSON but it did not have the "crs" record. It starts with this code

Comment: {"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[318236.529,4840171.519],[318236.25,4840170.941],

Comment: I checked ORG2GUI and it appears to be a Windows utility so that would be difficult to test,

Comment: If you can download a shapefile from the same source then the switch is relatively trivial since you will know the projection with certainty. Otherwise, you could try defining the existing projection to UTM zone 17N in whichever tool you are using and then reproject (mapshaper, ORG2GUI, qGIS, arcGIS, proj4js, etc all will allow this, some more easily than others). Here's the projection I think you are looking at: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83-utm-zone-17n/

Comment: I don't have access to the original source but I have managed to created a geojson file that looks similar {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "WARD_WGS84",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "AREA_ID": 2551040, "AREA_TYPE": "WD18", "AREA_S_CD": "16", "AREA_L_CD": "16", "AREA_NAME": "Don Valley East", "X": 318237.29, "Y": 4844000.0, "LONGITUDE": -79.33298, "LATITUDE":  - the property names are different

Comment: I managed to generate a geojson file but when I preview it there is an underlying map https://github.com/PatriciaW43/wards25/blob/master/map.geojson can I remove it? I just want to see the ward outlines